# Sitecore 10.2 Smart Publish Not Publishing Versions to CD Server

Tags: publishing

I am currently running into a strange problem with our `10.2` environment that we are upgrading from `9.0.2`. It has previously been working. However, when we did our latest database migration from existing production (`9.0.2`) to our `10.2` environment. We started running into a problem when doing a "Site Publish" where Sitecore will first publish the content to our CD environment and then remove our only version (english) from those items before completing the Site Publish.

This results the client facing CD environment to virtually have none of its content - mostly just blank pages. Checking the content in the web DB and it looks like the items are physically there - just no versions are available and get the message:

```
The current item does not have a version in "English : English".
To create a version, click Add a New Version or click Add on the Versions tab.
```

This happens for all content and there are no custom pipeline processors manipulating items... Watching the trace during live view/logs doesn't reveal anything out of the ordinary.

Furthermore, while the publish is taking place, you can see in the web db that the versions are there. Then at the very end right before the publish of master to web completes it removes all the item versions

I was wondering if anyone has run into this problem before or might have some suggestions on what to do to fix this?

Comment: Make sure your language items are published

Comment: @MarkCassidy they are published. That seems to be one of the only things that remains published actually.

Comment: Do you have any other Language in site? and set as default by mistake ? Do you have workflow ? If yes, just get rid of it for instance and try.

Comment: What happens if you manually publish 1 item at time along path? I.e sitecore/content/home/item1/item2/item3 do they all stay published? Then, go back and publish sitecore root?

Comment: Did you run the sitecore.update application to clean database items on both master AND Web?

Comment: @VikrantPunwatkar, we do have other languages but only "en" is set to default. We have workflows, but I dont believe they are being utilized at this time. We can try removing them just to rule that out though.

Comment: @DeanOBrien Manually publishing items will push them out to CD and they will stay there until a Site Publish happens. From there, they are removed as if they were never there. We did run the sitecore.update application to clean all dbs and this issue persisted. We even ran a fresh backup and tried again. Then we tried using a fresh 10.2 web db and publish to that with no success.

Comment: One possible cause could be related to publishing restrictions and settings
. It is recommended to check the publishing settings and restrictions for the items that are not being published. Another possible cause could be related to the upgrade process from 9.0.2 to 10.2. Please check the Sitecore logs and event viewer for any error messages that could provide more information about the issue.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? Can you check if all the root items (I.e. sitecore, content and home) exist in master DB, but not in Web. This needs to be done via SSMS, rather than sitecore UI. As sitcoe merges items from .dat files with sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this was right under my nose the whole time, but to anyone that struggles with this in the future...

While I checked to makes sure the `English` language itself had been published to the `Web` db. I did not notice that the `system/languages` folder item did not have a version.

Once I added an `English version` for the `system/languages` folder and published it everything thing else published correctly when doing a Site Publish.